# TinyMCE saves html tags in database.How to store data without thm tags?

Tags: php, html, security, laravel-5, wysiwyg

I am using TinyMCE editor.When I am saving data into database it is storing HTML tags as well.I have used strip_tags() but did not got work.

When I try to store It Is storing like this `<strong>paragraph</strong>` in database.Can anyone tell how to store data without HTML tags in database.

First image Is my current output and second image Is my desired output.

[image: First image Is my current output and second image Is my desired output.]

[image]

Comment: "without loosing HTML effect" - what do you mean? HTML tags are what give the "HTML effect"

Comment: It is not possible to keep html effects without html tags. u must need to store data with html tags to keep html output otherwise it will convert into plain text.

Comment: when I use strip_tags()  HTML effects are gone and it stores only text.But i want only text to store in database but while showing contents it should show HTML effects

Comment: when I use this strip_tags($a['name']."<b>" It gives me proper result like It stores plain text in database and shows text with bold effect. I do not want to show particular effect like <b> tag.It should be flexible with <p> <i> or any other tags

Comment: @Shweta provide your code snippet and screen shots. Your question is confusing us.

Comment: why would you need to remove html formatting?

Comment: because of security issues and I have read that HTML tags should not be stored in Mysql.I have read that It is bad practice.

Comment: @Shweta It not a bad practice in this case. You should understand the purpose of using WYSIWYG editors. TinyMCE is an HTML based editor which preserves the text formatting using HTML! You can just remove the tags and preserve formatting. If you do not want to store HTML tags, better do not use TinyMCE. Just us plain textarea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105969/discussion-between-brainless-and-shweta).

Answer (score 1):

It is storing the data just fine. If you remove the HTML tags, you will lose the formatting made on the editor.

You cannot store a plain text in DB and maintain text formatting at the same time.

**Solution:**

I think you are looking for something like [htmLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/). There is a [packagist wrapper available here](https://packagist.org/packages/vanilla/htmlawed). This will just strip the vulnerabilities and sanitize your HTML.

**Usage:**

Just add the below to your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "vanilla/htmlawed": "~1.0"
}
```

and run `composer update`

```
$xss = "<i>nothing to see <script>alert('xss')</script>";

// Pass an empty config and spec for no filtering of malicious code.
echo Htmlawed::filter($xss, [], []);
// Outputs: '<i>nothing to see <script type="text/javascript">alert("xss")</script></i>'

// Pass safe=1 to turn on all the safe options.
echo Htmlawed::filter($xss, ['safe' => 1]);
// Outputs: '<i>nothing to see alert("xss")</i>'

// We provide a convenience method that strips all tags that aren't supposed to be in rss feeds.
echo Htmlawed::filterRSS('<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>');
// Outputs: '<h1>Hello world!</h1>'
```

**Example:**

```
{!! Htmlawed::filter($richText, ['safe'=>1]) !!} //Blade style
```

OR

```
echo Htmlawed::filter($richText, ['safe'=>1]); //PHP style
```

Note: I have not used `{{ }}`. By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following `{!! $name !!}`.